# assign the textbox value to label in next form

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, label

I just want to know how to assign a value entered in a textbox to label in the next form.

example: I have 3 windows forms  1st page is login page, second page is a gridview and third form is a button located in a gridview when i click a button the form will open.

Now when i enter a name in login page i.e., username it should be reflected in 3rd form.

I have tried like below

In button click i wrote the code like

```
chat frm = new chat();
frm.LabelText = txtusername.Text;

frm.ShowDialog();
```

and form3 load i worte the code like

```
private string labelText;
public string LabelText { get { return labelText; } set { labelText = value; } }

label3.Text = LabelText;
```

but when i click login button it directly opens form3 but i want form2 should open first and when i click the button in the gridview form3 should open.

Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to declare a class having a `public static string LabelText` and use it to get/set the username:

```
class MyClass
{
public static string LabelText = "";
}
```

Then use this code to set it:

```
chat frm = new chat();
MyClass.LabelText = txtusername.Text;

frm.ShowDialog();
```

Then on `form3` use this code to get it back:

```
label3.Text = MyClass.LabelText;
```

This way you wont have to define `getter/setter` properties on each form.

Comment: Its working but when i click login button it should not open form3 it should open form2 and in my form2 i have a button for form3 then only it should open and label has to change accordingly.